# Upvote failed on Meta question using iOS iPad App

Tags: bug, ios-app, ipad

I tried to upvote [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow) on Meta Stack Overflow using the Stack Exchange iOS App Version 1.1.0.127 (current version right now). I have a 4th generation iPad with iOS 8.0.

Got an error message stating:

"Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta."

Dutifully, I then tried logging off and in again, with the same results. I was able to upvote the question by using the mobile app on Safari, no errors at all.

I also can upvote other questions and answers in SO using the iOS app, so this might be related to the specific question/site.

Thanks for all the hard work! The app is already great on iPad!

Comment: You can upvote other questions on meta.SO? and answers?

Comment: Yes, to be sure, I've just looked for a good question and upvoted it. Also the answer.

Comment: That particular question has seen some status changes over the last couple of days but at the moment the only difference I can see is that it is tagged as featured. We have to wait for a dev to investigate/repro.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with my 3rd generation iPad, iOS 7.1.2, same app version

Comment: @VMai it has to be done on a meta of a site you don't have account in just yet, or maybe also meta you never visited before. (first visit should auto-create account)

Comment: I had this same problem yesterday with the newest iOS app version 1.3.0.208 on iPad 2. It was a site where I have an account, and was logged in. @ShadowWizard, I can't remember whether or not I've been to that meta, so that might have been it. I hope it gets fixed, though, so I don't have to go to Safari each time I try to vote at a new meta!

Comment: Sure @Sue, no doubt there's a bug here. You can ping Brian in chat just in case he missed this bug... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Will do! I've chatted with him before and he's always kind, and encourages people to let him know how the app can be its most helpful!